# import Northwind db to laravel

Tags: laravel, migration, northwind

I am trying to import/use Northwind db in my Laravel project.
Since when creating Laravel project you're required to create models, migrations and such, i want to ask, is there some automatized way of importing it, with model and migration creating, or that is only doable by hand?

Another question: I tried adding foreign key constraint to one the tables, and also tried tried to migrate that specific change by creating subfolder in migrations:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/north/
```

where "north" is subfolder in which is specific migration is located and

```
        Schema::table('order_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger("OrderID")->nullable();
            $table->foreign("OrderID")->references("OrderID")->on("orders")->onDelete("cascade");

        });
```

is code for creating foreign key.

Questions:

1. Is there automatized way for importing Northwind or any db not created in Laravel, or i have to do all by hand?
2. If i have to do by hand, then why the way of adding fk constraint doesn't work? Am i missing something? Explanation: When i try to migrate, it says: "Nothing to migrate".

Comment: Take a look at this github repository:https://github.com/Algo-Web/POData-Laravel-NorthWind

Comment: @Collin I already saw it while searching the way before i asked on SO. In it's readme doesn't explain what it actually does. Is it doing what i asked?

Comment: For as far as i can see it's worth the try

Comment: Ok, i'll try it blindly. Event if it's doesn't explain what does exactly.